# How to type hint when a method returns an instance of a subclass when the subclass type is an attribute of the parent class?

Tags: python, inheritance, types, mypy, python-typing

I am trying to figure out how to type hint the `__add__` method in the `A_single` class below.

(Detailed explanation of the code below the code block.)

```py
from typing import Optional

class A_single:
    def __init__(self, a: str, add_to_type: Optional[type] = None) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self.add_to_type = A_add_to if add_to_type is None else add_to_type

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, A_single):
            return self.add_to_type(self, other)

        if isinstance(other, self.add_to_type):
            other_tup = tuple(type(self)(a) for a in other.a_tuple)
            out_tup = (self,) + other_tup
            return self.add_to_type(*out_tup)

class A_add_to:
    def __init__(self, *a_s: A_single) -> None:
        self.a_tuple = tuple([a_instance.a for a_instance in a_s])

class B_single(A_single):
    def __init__(self, a: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(a, add_to_type=B_add_to)

class B_add_to(A_add_to):
    ...

class C_single(A_single):
    def __init__(self, a: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(a, add_to_type=C_add_to)

class C_add_to(A_add_to):
    ...
```

Class A defines how all its subclass adds to each other.
For example:

- `B_single` (subclass of `A_single`) + `B_single` (subclass of `A_single`) becomes `B_add_to` (subclass of `A_add_to`),
- `C_single` (subclass of `A_single`) + `C_single` (subclass of `A_single`) becomes `C_add_to` (subclass of `A_add_to`)

The code above is a super simple toy example.
In practice, I may have multiple subclasses of `A_single` and `A_add_to` which add the "single" type to their corresponding "add_to" type in the exact same way, so I pass in the name of the "add_to" type and let the `__add__` method in the parent class `A` to determine which "add_to" type it should return.

My question is:

Is there a way to access the `self.add_to_type` when I try to type hint `other` in `def __add__(self, other)`?

Here is what I attempted to do:

```py
from typing import Union
from typing_extensions import Self

class A:
    def __init__(self, a: str, add_to_type: Optional[type] = None) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self.add_to_type = A_add_to if add_to_type is None else add_to_type

    def __add__(self, other: Union[Self, Self.add_to_type]) -> Self.add_to_type: 
        if isinstance(other, A):
            return self.add_to_type(self, other)
        
        if isinstance(other, self.add_to_type):
            other_tup = tuple(type(self)(a) for a in other.a_tuple)
            out_tup = (self,) + other_tup
            return self.add_to_type(*out_tup)
```

However, the `mypy` type checker says

```
The name "Self.add_to_type" is not defined
```

What will be the proper way to type hint the `__add__` method?

Comment: You could make `A` generic in that type, I guess: `class A(Generic[_T])`, then `@overload def __init__(self: A[A_add_to], a: str, add_to_type: None = ...)` `@overload def __init__(self, a: str, add_to_type: _T)` and finally `def __add__(sef, other: Self | _T)`

Comment: Is there a _1:1_ relationship (or at least _n:1_) between subclasses of `A_single` and subclasses of `A_add_to`? I.e. is the `add_to` type fixed for any given `single` type? Your `single` subclasses' constructors suggest so. But you still take an `add_to` type as an `__init__` argument. Do you really _need_ that in the constructor or could it also just be a class attribute?